# Unnecessary packages on my Ubuntu VPS server from host. How to diff with standard Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, server, 13.10

The Ubuntu setup & packages  that I got on my VPS from my host provider seems to be quite different from default Ubuntu server *minimal* edition. For e.g. I could see some not-so-necessary packages like samba, procmail, sound-theme-freedesktop, bluez & many others,  have been installed by default. Well in a minimal server installation, does having these make sense?

Is there any way I could compare the Ubuntu I got from the host with the standard Official Ubuntu ? Some way could I `diff` my setup with the standard Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

- You get all packages available in the server release CD, but not all installed by default

  ```
  wget -q -O - http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64.list | xargs -I{} basename {} | cut -d _ -f1 | sort > pkg-available.cd.list
  ```
- To compare to a running machine you can.

  1. Generate the list of installed packages

     ```
     dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | cut -f1 > pkg-installed.server1.list
     ```

     and for 2nd machine

     ```
     dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | cut -f1 > pkg-installed.server2.list
     ```
  2. Compare them

     ```
     diff -y pkg-installed.server*.list
     ```

     or to the available ones in the CD

     ```
     diff -y pkg-installed.server1.list pkg-available.cd.list
     ```